# Fast SSH login into Ubuntu local machine but performance degrades over time

Tags: ssh, 22.04

When I first login into my Ubuntu local machine via SSH from another Ubuntu machine, the server is extremely responsive and there is no delay in the terminal. However, after some time, the delay starts to build up and I have to start up a new SSH session to return to the previous responsiveness.

What could be some reasons for this problem?

Comment: Wired ethernet or WiFi? If WiFi, what's your MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit)? `ip link` will show. WiFi MTU should be 1492, not 1500. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.